# Linha de tendencia em scatterplot no matplotlib em Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Supondo que eu tenha duas listas simples em Python e crie um gráfico de dispersão:

```
x = [548, 677, 987, 2, 29, 1114, 521, 999] 
y = [96, 775, 258, 369, 410, 99, 5, 1117]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Como posso criar uma linha de tendência dentro desse mesmo gráfico?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso rapidamente através da [função Polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) do `numpy`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [548, 677, 987, 2, 29, 1114, 521, 999] 
y = [96, 775, 258, 369, 410, 99, 5, 1117]

plt.scatter(x, y)

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")
```

**Saída:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa que eu fiz é o basicão, mas dá pra fazer algumas coisas bem legais, [como você pode ver aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635448/how-can-i-draw-scatter-trend-line-on-matplot-python-pandas/41635626).